# How to remove duplicated values by row but keeping the row and specific row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset and would like to remove duplicated values with nothing but keep those rows. Here is what I have:

df =

```
 id     column_a     column_b      column_c     name
 101      abc          def           ghi        adam
 101      abc          def           ghi        brook
 101      abc          def           ghi        chris
```

I would like to only keep the top row untouched but all the other rows with the same `id` value have all values removed but rows not deleted, only leaving `id` and `name` column to be present. Like this:

```
id      column_a      column_b     column_c      name 
101       abc            def          ghi        adam
101                                              brook
101                                              chris
```

I did `df['column_a'] = np.where(df['id'] = df['id'].shift(1), '', df['column_a']` and this seems to have worked I was just trying to find a more effective way to do so. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't removing, it's *replacing* with empty strings.

Comment: Your code doesn't check whether `column_a` is actually duplicated. It's looking for duplicated `id` and then replaces `column_a`. Does a duplicate id always have duplicate column a, b, and c?

Comment: @Barmar `id` does always have duplicated rows

Comment: @Coding_Nubie always have some duplicates or it's only one value?

Comment: @mozway sorry for the late response but always have some duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the desired columns with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
ignore = ['id', 'name']

out = (df[ignore].combine_first(
            df.drop(columns=ignore)
              .apply(lambda s: s.mask(s.duplicated(), ''))
            )
       [df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
    id column_a column_b column_c   name
0  101      abc      def      ghi   adam
1  101                             brook
2  101                             chris
```

Per group:

```
ignore = ['id', 'name']
out = (df[ignore]
       .combine_first(df.drop(columns=ignore)
                        .apply(lambda s: s.mask(s.groupby(df['id'])
                                                 .transform(lambda s: s.duplicated()),
                                                '')))
       [df.columns]
      )
```

Example:

```
    id column_a column_b column_c   name
0  101      abc      def      ghi   adam
1  101                             brook
2  101                             chris
3  102      abc      def      ghi  chris
```